Full-rank matrix
Let we have a nonnegative-definite matrix $X\ne0$, and a rectangular full-rank matrix $C$ of appropriate dimensions. Is it possible to prove that $C^TXC\ne0$?

I'm assuming that $C$ is not a square matrix, right?

Yes, $C$ is rectangular matrix.

I do believe $X=O$ is nonnegative-definite?

Sure, but it is obvious case. And what for nonzero $X$?

Let $X$ be an $m\times m$ matrix, $C$ be an $m\times n$ matrix of full rank. Consider two cases:

$m\le n$: Here the matrix $CC^T$ is nondegenerate, so
$$C(C^TXC)C^T=(CC^T)X(CC^T)$$
have the same rank as $X$, therefore it is non-zero. So $C^TXC$ is non-zero as well.

$m>n$: Consider symmetric $Y$ such that $Y^2=X$. $\operatorname{rank} Y=\operatorname{rank} X$. Then $C^TXC=C^TYYC=(YC)^T(YC)$, so $\operatorname{rank}C^TXC=\operatorname{rank}YC$.
Note that $\operatorname{rank}YC=0$ (or $YC=0$ itself) $\iff$ $\operatorname{Im}C\subset\operatorname{Ker}Y$.
So if $\operatorname{rank}{Y}=\operatorname{rank}{X}>m-\operatorname{rank}C=m-n$ then $YC\ne0$ and $C^TXC\ne0$.
And if $\operatorname{rank}{X}\le m-n$ then there exists a full-rank $C$ such that $CXC^T=0$ ($C^T$ can be constructed from basis vectors of $\operatorname{Ker}X$).


